# Special characters in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, encoding, url, google-search

If I search for something containing non-ASCII characters from the address bar, *using Google as the default search engine*, any result that features the special characters in its URL is broken (the URL is decoded as ASCII rather than UTF-8).

The strange thing is that this only happens in Chrome, and only with the Google search engine. It's fine when searching Google from Firefox, or searching Bing from Chrome, for example.

For example, the second result for **[déclencheur](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=d%C3%A9clencheur&qscrl=1)** takes me to [`http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-english/d%C3%83%C2%A9clencheur`](http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-english/d%C3%83%C2%A9clencheur).

I've tried changing the encoding settings for Chrome but with no effect. Can anyone else reproduce this? Is it a bug in Chrome or the search engine itself?

**Update:** It seems to work fine when searching via Google Instant, but not when JavaScript is disabled and not from the address bar (and not from the link above, either) – the plot thickens!

**Edit:** Better example of broken search: URL of first result for **[wiktionary é](http://www.google.co.uk/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=wiktionary+%C3%A9&qscrl=1)** (when not searched for via Google Instant) is

> [`http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%83%C2%A9`](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%83%C2%A9)

but should be

> [`http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A9`](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A9)

Comment: I can confirm that it doesn't work on Chrome (Linux build) 11.0.696.34 beta

Comment: @MaxMackie: Thanks, good to know it's not just me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the second link in Google's results for déclencheur. It works OK in Chrome version 10.0.648.204 on Windows Vista.

Comment: Bizarre – that's the same version as me. I want to submit a bug report but I don't know where I should submit it!

Comment: @WillVousden: Go to **Wrench > Tools > Report an issue**.